# SqlServer 2005: deadlock problem with no shared records

Tags: sql-server-2005, deadlock

I have a deadlock problem with two transactions that do not access any common records. There is also no lock escalation. So I can't explain why a deadlock is possible.

The deadlock occurs when two such transactions are executed at the same time:

```
begin transaction

update A set [value] = [value]
where id = 1; /* resp. 2 */

/* synchronize transactions here */

SELECT * 
FROM  
 A inner join B on A.B_FK = B.id
 inner join C on C.A_FK = A.id
WHERE 
 A.[value] = 1; /* resp. 2 */

rollback;
```

These are the tables and data to setup the scenario:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  [value] INT,
  B_FK INT
  primary key (id)
)

CREATE TABLE B (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  primary key (id)
)

CREATE TABLE C (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  A_FK INT
  primary key (id)
)

INSERT INTO A VALUES(1, 1, 1) 
INSERT INTO B VALUES(1) 
INSERT INTO C VALUES(1, 1) 

INSERT INTO A VALUES(2, 2, 2) 
INSERT INTO B VALUES(2) 
INSERT INTO C VALUES(2, 2)
```

Table `A` is in the middle of three tables. If I change anything in the query, for instance remove one of the joined tables `B` or `C`, there is no deadlock. The same when I filter by `A.id` instead of `A.value`.

The deadlock-graph tells me that they both want to set an S lock to the primary key index of table `A`. Again: there is no lock escalation.

I'm using SqlServer 2005.

- Why are these transactions conflicting without accessing any common data? Can anyone explain this?
- What can I do to avoid it? I'm using NHibernate and can not change the query that easily.
- Could it be an SqlServer issue?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what does "/* synchronize transactions here */" mean?

Comment: @Mitch: It means that I run transaction 1 until this point, then run transaction 2, which waits on the select, then I run transaction 1 to the end, which also waits on the select.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger when first transaction would execute update statement, the second transaction would wait at the update statement and cannot proceed further till first transaction commits.
How is deadlock possible here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The conflict could happen, because SQL-Server does locking not only on row level, but also on page or even table level.

That means a record can be locked even though it is not actually in use itself, but only a different record "nearby".

[SQL Server Lock Contention Tamed](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2000/lock-contention-nolock-rowlock/) might be helpful

Comment: Yes - if it can't obtain row-level locking, it escalates to page and then table.

Comment: But isn't this a lock escalation? Shouldn't it be traced in the profiler?

Comment: From my understanding Sql Server could decide to use page locking from the start. In that case there would be no escalation.

Comment: Thanks for the notice. Seems the article was moved to a new location. I updated the link so it should be working again

Answer (score 1):

Also, another thing to consider when you sometimes get these problems is that the locking could come from processing done by triggers.

Comment: Fortunately, I don't have any triggers in the db. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why triggers make any difference?

Comment: triggers may update other tables, which can reduce concurrency & this looks like an unexpected lock if you didn't realise there was a trigger present