# SQL Server exclusive row lock (XLOCK ROWLOCK) using Spring Transactions using Hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, spring, transactions

I am attempting to do a select on a row and update the value.  While I do this I need exclusive access to the row.  In other words, no other process (inside or outside the VM), should be able to read the row until after I update the row.  The current value should not be "selectable".  I have tried the following transaction annotation.

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE, readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class, timeout=960)
```

This definitely works within the Spring context, but while putting a sleep statement in the middle of the transaction, I'm still able to select the current row value using a database tool.

Is there a way to get a XLOCK/ROWLOCK (whichever is the appropriate) using Spring/Hibernate?

**Versions:**

- Spring: 3.0.5.RELEASE
- Hibernate: 3.6.3.Final
- JTDS: 1.2.4

If I can't use Spring/Hibernate, a link to a JTDS example would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: did you try the other way around issuing a select with a "for update" suffix on the database tool and then try running the program from the application ? You may have to check the isolation level in the tool also, before running the above query.

Comment: I will try that.  It could be I'm already acquiring the kind of lock I need without making any changes.

Comment: I think that should definetly tell you what is happening, please update is you see that it is not locking.

Comment: I can't do a "FOR UPDATE", but when I used "with (paglock,XLOCK)", I seemed to get the locking I wanted.  If you post your answer, I will give you the bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SERIALIZABLE` isolation level allows other transactions to read data, but not to modify. So you need to explicitly `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` (in Hibernate: `Query#setLockMode(LockMode.UPGRADE)`).

Comment: Can you do a "FOR UPDATE" in SQL Server

Comment: Sure. [Somebody](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483725) has already exercised that.

Answer (score 2):

Use explicit locking with the Hibernate. There is more information [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-locking).

However, I think you have to think once more time - do you really need the pessimistic lock? In most cases optimistic lock works better, and hibernate supports versioning very well.

Comment: This table used as a sequence.  I believe I need pessimistic locking to ensure no other process uses the value before I use it and increment it.

Comment: Do you need gap-less sequence?

Comment: I doubt it is a requirement.  Why?

Comment: You are unlucky... ;) Try to fight it first http://www.gplivna.eu/papers/gapless_sequences.htm . You also should put a create "document" transaction for which you generate the number inside your method. Otherwise, it could have gaps in case if a document creation has been rolled back.